# Change <div> automatically JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I have few Icons, when I click on one the image on the other div changes, I can change the image with the click but I want to be changing images automatically and when the user clicks on one icon it shows that one.

Edit: The user clicks the right icons and the big image changes.. Want to make this change in a timeinterval automatically and if th euser clicks on one change it too.

Icons the user clicks

```
 <div class="col-md-3 laptopNormal">
                <div class="img-responsive">
                    <img class="hvr-grow wow fadeInLeft logoa wnormal" data-link="1" src="http://placehold.it/130x130">
                </div>
                <div class="img-responsive">
                    <img class="hvr-grow wow fadeInRight logoa wnormal" data-link="2" src="http://placehold.it/130x130">
                </div>
                <div class="img-responsive">
                    <img class="hvr-grow wow fadeInUp logoa wnormal" data-link="3" src="http://placehold.it/130x130">
                </div>
                <div class="img-responsive">
                    <img class="hvr-grow wow fadeInLeft logoa wnormal" data-link="4" src="http://placehold.it/130x130">
                </div>
                <div class="img-responsive">
                    <img class="hvr-grow wow fadeInRight logoa wnormal" data-link="5" src="http://placehold.it/130x130" >
                </div>
            </div>
```

Images that show when clicking

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="wow fadeInLeft twomacsbg" style="height: inherit;">
                    <img class="monitores wow fadeInRight iconsresp" data-link="1" src="http://placehold.it/130x130" >
                    <img class="monitores iconsresp" data-link="2" src="http://placehold.it/130x130" >
                    <img class="monitores  fadeInRight iconsresp" data-link="3" src="http://placehold.it/130x130" >
                    <img class="monitores  fadeInRight iconsresp" data-link="4" src="http://placehold.it/130x130" >
                    <img class="monitores  fadeInRight iconsresp" data-link="5" src="http://placehold.it/130x130" >
                </div>
            </div>
```

my javascript

```
 $('.monitores:not(:nth-child(1))').hide();
    $('.logoa').click(
        function() {
            $('.monitores').hide();
            $('.monitores[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn();
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by automatically ? like `setInterval()` ?

Comment: try to make a snippet for easier testing and exactly what do you mean with change images automatically

Comment: @mikepa88 Edited! Check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the first image to visible and the rest to invisible. Then move the images to the start to view them. In the interval, move the first element to the end.

```
window.setInterval( function(){
    var first = $(".monitores:first-of-type").remove();
    $(".monitores").parent().append(first);
}, 3000);

$(document).on("click",".logoa",function() {
     var element =  $('.monitores[data-link=' + $(this).attr('data-link') + ']').remove();
     $(".monitores").parent().prepend(element);
});
```

css:

```
.monitores{display:none;}
.monitores:first-of-type{display:block;}
```

css for fade-in transition:

```
.monitores{opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s;}
.monitores:first-of-type{opacity: 1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$(document).on("click",".logoa",function() {
    $('.monitores').hide();
    $('.monitores[data-link=' + $(this).attr('data-link') + ']').fadeIn();
});
```